# how to convert timestamp to ISO date in mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using node.js mongodb client.
I have a timestamp value in a collection, now I want to use aggregate to convert timestamp to IOSDate, so I can compare it easily. But I do not know how to do it.

```
   var db = game.getDB();
    var coll = db.collection("LoginRecord");
    coll.aggregate([
        {
            $project: {
                "PT" : 1,
                "PID" : 1,
                "regDate" : new Date("$createTime"), //#####createTime is a timestamp, I want to convert it to IOSDate
                "loginDay" : { $dayOfYear : "$_serverDate"}
            }
        },
        {
            $group : {
                "_id" : "$loginDay",
                "logUsers" : { $addToSet: "$PID"}
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind : "$logUsers"
        },
        {
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$_id",
                "logCount" : { $sum: 1}
            }
        }
    ], function(err, res) {
        logger.info("aggregate res " + JSON.stringify(res));
    });
```

Comment: You cannot do that. The JavaScript functions you are using evaluate "outside" and "before" the pipeline content is sent to the server. You cannot use arbitrary code on elements during pipeline execution. You will either need to work with the timestamp values to determine "dayOfYear" ( very complex and I'm "fairly" sure the aggregation framework does not have the necessary math operators to handle it ). Or otherwise convert your collection to use Date types instead. But you cannot cast this way inside pipeline execution.

Comment: If my mongodb client is c++, how can I make a json value which has a time value, when the json is sent to mongodb, the date value will be automatically saved as a ISODate value ? how can I accomplish it?

Comment: The driver library will have a date object type. If your not sure how to use it then post another question. What you are trying to do here is not possible as per my explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Mongodb 4.0 has introduced [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) aggregation which simply convert timestamp to ISO date

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "regDate": { "$toDate": "$createTime" }
  }}
])
```

You can try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GDHbUfI1GiV)

Answer (score 3):

As referred [convert milliseconds to date in mongodb aggregation pipeline for group by?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892152/convert-milliseconds-to-date-in-mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-for-group-by)

You can do it as follows to convert milliseconds (timestamp) to date object:

```
"regDate": {
   $add: [ new Date(0), "$createTime" ]
}
```

Comment: Timestamp are 64bit numbers of seconds in low & high. Until 4.0 $add doesn't allow Timestamp data.

Answer (score 2):

Before using the aggregation framework, just query the collection and update the documents to ISODate date format. Mongodb timestamp objects for internal use only. So you should make this a permanently switch the type to ISODate.
Link to [warning.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB offers no easy way to do this, unfortunatelly.

The way I solved it was using the `map` function to inject a *date* field into the result.

First, setup a date conversion function, like the one below:

```
function toDateStr(ts) {
    let dataF = new Date();   dataF.setTime(ts);
    let strDataF = dataF.toLocaleString();
    return strDataF;
}
```

Then, in your aggregate, just call this function on each document and insert a new date field. Like so:

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
     {
       $project: {
            timestamp: 1
          }
      },
      {
          $match: { /* something */
          }
      }
   ]
).map(function(doc) {
    doc['date'] = toDateStr(doc.timestamp);
    return doc
})
```