# convert milliseconds to date in mongodb aggregation pipeline for group by?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have to convert milliseconds to date format in mongodb aggregation pipiline -

My query is -

```
db.campaign_wallet.aggregate({"$match" : {"campaignId" : 1, "txnTime" : { "$gte" : 1429554600000, "$lte" : 1430159400000}}}, {"$group" : {"_id" : {"msisdn" : "$msisdn", "txnTime" : "$txnTime"}, "count" : {"$sum": 1}}});
```

In this query how to convert txnTime (which is in milliseconds) to date in pipeline ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert miliseconds to date in mongodb aggregation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889719/how-to-convert-miliseconds-to-date-in-mongodb-aggregation)

Comment: @chridam This is new question and in this i have to convert miliseconds to date in the pipeline....can you solve it ?

Comment: @AmitDas Please post actual text of the query instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @ZeMoon added that...now check

Comment: @AmitDas At which pipeline stage do you want that field converted? If you want to filter the documents based on some date range then use the projection in my answer to this [**duplicate**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889719/how-to-convert-miliseconds-to-date-in-mongodb-aggregation) as the first pipeline stage then do the `$match` and `$group` operations based on the projected date field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In MongoDB $project clause, how can I convert date from milliseconds to ISODate object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698265/in-mongodb-project-clause-how-can-i-convert-date-from-milliseconds-to-isodate)

Comment: @chridam I want to group by msisdn feild and txnTime feild to achieve unique msisdn with unique date

Comment: @AmitDas Help me to understand your objective here; won't the timestamp field alone give you a unique date? Converting milliseconds to a date will be an overhead because the timestamp in milliseconds is essentially a datetime value.

Comment: @chridam .... I have to change milliseconds to date format for "txnTime" feild in the groupby pipeline. In my collection , the "txnTime" feild is in milliseconds.

Comment: @chridam Only if it is milliseconds difference to a fixed date. ;) though it looks like msecs since epoch, we can't be sure of that.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg So true, how a milisecond difference in datetime will make a huge impact in the uniqueness of a field :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm trying to get the logic behind converting the `txnTime` field to a date object because grouping by either a date field or a timestamp in milliseconds (like what you are presently doing) will yield the same result as they both are unique in their respective formats!

To change the `txnTime` field to a date object you should then include a [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project) pipeline before the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) pipeline stage with this expression

```
"txnTime": {
    "$add": [ new Date(0), "$txnTime" ]
}
```

so that you can do your [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operation on the converted/projected txnTime field:

```
var convertedTxnTime = { "$add": [new Date(0), "$txnTime"] };

/*
  If using MongoDB 4.0 and newer, use $toDate 

  var convertedTxnTime = { "$toDate": "$txnTime" };

  or $convert

  var convertedTxnTime = { "$convert": { "input": "$txnTime", "to": "date" } };

*/

db.campaign_wallet.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "campaignId" : 1 , 
        "txnTime" : { 
            "$gte" : 1429554600000 , 
            "$lte" : 1430159400000
        }
    } },
    { "$group" : { 
        "_id" : {
            "txnTime": convertedTxnTime,
            "msisdn" : "$msisdn"
        }, 
        "msisdnCount" : { "$sum" : 1}
    } }
]);
```

**Output**: (based on the sample documents from this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889719/how-to-convert-miliseconds-to-date-in-mongodb-aggregation)**)

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "txnTime" : ISODate("2015-04-25T18:30:00.000Z"),
                "msisdn" : "91808770101"
            },
            "msisdnCount" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "txnTime" : ISODate("2015-04-27T05:11:54.796Z"),
                "msisdn" : "9180877010"
            },
            "msisdnCount" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "txnTime" : ISODate("2015-04-25T18:30:01.111Z"),
                "msisdn" : "91808070101"
            },
            "msisdnCount" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "txnTime" : ISODate("2015-04-25T18:30:00.000Z"),
                "msisdn" : "91808070101"
            },
            "msisdnCount" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "txnTime" : ISODate("2015-04-27T05:11:54.796Z"),
                "msisdn" : "9189877000"
            },
            "msisdnCount" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "txnTime" : ISODate("2015-04-27T05:11:54.796Z"),
                "msisdn" : "9189877667"
            },
            "msisdnCount" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

-- **UPDATE** --

To group the documents by date with the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, use the **[Date Aggregation Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/)**

Example:

```
var convertedTxnTime = { "$add": [new Date(0), "$txnTime"] };

/*
  If using MongoDB 4.0 and newer, use $toDate 

  var convertedTxnTime = { "$toDate": "$txnTime" };

  or $convert

  var convertedTxnTime = { "$convert": { "input": "$txnTime", "to": "date" } };

*/

db.campaign_wallet.aggregate([
    { "$match": { 
        "campaignId" : 1 , 
        "txnTime" : { 
            "$gte" : 1429554600000 , 
            "$lte" : 1430159400000
        }
    } },
    { "$group" : { 
        "_id" : {
            "txnTime_year" : { "$year": convertedTxnTime },
            "txnTime_month" : { "$month": convertedTxnTime },
            "txnTime_day" : { "$dayOfMonth": convertedTxnTime },
            "msisdn": "$msisdn"
        }, 
        "msisdnCount" : { "$sum" : 1}
    } }
]);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "txnTime_year" : 2015,
                "txnTime_month" : 4,
                "txnTime_day" : 25,
                "msisdn" : "91808770101"
            },
            "msisdnCount" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "txnTime_year" : 2015,
                "txnTime_month" : 4,
                "txnTime_day" : 25,
                "msisdn" : "91808070101"
            },
            "msisdnCount" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "txnTime_year" : 2015,
                "txnTime_month" : 4,
                "txnTime_day" : 27,
                "msisdn" : "9180877010"
            },
            "msisdnCount" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "txnTime_year" : 2015,
                "txnTime_month" : 4,
                "txnTime_day" : 27,
                "msisdn" : "9189877000"
            },
            "msisdnCount" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "txnTime_year" : 2015,
                "txnTime_month" : 4,
                "txnTime_day" : 27,
                "msisdn" : "9189877667"
            },
            "msisdnCount" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: this is almost right .... but msisdn = "91808070101" was on same date ....so its entry in the result should be like this -

{
            "_id" : {
                "txnTime" : ISODate("2015-04-25"),
                "msisdn" : "91808070101"
            },
            "msisdnCount" : 3
        },

Comment: @AmitDas I've updated the answer to this effect. It would be great if you could be more elaborate in your questions, be specific with the objectives as I couldn't really understand what you wanted in the first place. I eventually got it that you want to group the documents by a date with the format `YYYY-MM-DD` as you finally mentioned in your comments.

Answer (score 4):

With mongodb 4.0 you can try [**`$toDate`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) aggregation to convert milliseconds to date format

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { 
    "campaignId" : 1 , 
    "txnTime" : { 
      "$gte" : 1429554600000 , 
      "$lte" : 1430159400000
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "toDate": {
      "$toDate": "$txnTime"
    }
  }}
])
```

You can try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6-RYH1VqZ09)