# How to use unixtime with $dateToString mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

is't possible to use unixtime with `$dateToString`.

this is the schema:

```
var wifiSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ID: String,
  Vendor: String,
  SSID: String,
  TimeStamp: {
    date: Number,
  },
  AP: String,
  MAC: String,
  ID_frame: String,
  RSSI: Number,
  Type: String
}, { collection: 'wifiScan' });

var wifi = mongoose.model('wifi', wifiSchema);
```

and this is the mongoose function:

```
wifi.aggregate([

  {$group:{_id:{"time" : "$TimeStamp.date"},uniqueCount: {$addToSet: "$MAC"}}},
  {$project:{"time":1,uniqueCustomerCount:{$size:"$uniqueCount"}, yearMonthDayUTC: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y/%m/%d", date: new Date('$$TimeStamp.date') } } } },
    {$sort:{'uniqueCustomerCount': -1 }}
    ]).limit(20).exec().then(notes => {
      res.status(200).json({data:notes});
      console.log(notes);
    });
```

The problem that I get an error on converting the date variable from unix fo date format using `$dateToString`, this is the result I get:

```
  { _id: { time: 1529235720000 },
    uniqueCustomerCount: 26,
    yearMonthDayUTC: '1970/01/01' } ]
```

I don't know why I get is as '`1970/01/01`'. thanks for the help.

**Second try:**

I have tried this $project example also:

```
 {$project:{"time":1,uniqueCustomerCount:{$size:"$uniqueCount"},"Time": { "$add": [ new Date(0), "$TimeStamp.date" ]} } },
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892152/convert-milliseconds-to-date-in-mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-for-group-by

Comment: @JohnnyHK I have tried to add that solution, but the same problem.

Comment: Ok, can you edit this question to show what you're trying now?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, I have updated the $project as  {$project:{"time":1,uniqueCustomerCount:{$size:"$uniqueCount"},"txnTime": { "$add": [ new Date(0), "$TimeStamp.date" ]} } },

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include that in context? Comments don't work well for code.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, please look to the second try.

Comment: You seem to be missing your `$dateToString` now.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, the same problem, I have add $dateToString for Time var, the same prob, I got "1970/01/01" as output

Comment: You need to keep your question updated with what you're trying so we can help you get it working.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, i you know the solution please share, I have share all the solutions that I have tried